# Fork() causing print statements to overlap

Tags: c, fork

I use fork to fork multiple child processes, but for some reason they print over each other here is an example.

```
Winning Child (5): 0
Child placed peice at: 6,4
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
Child placed peice at: 2,6
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
Child placed peice at: 4,1
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
Child placed peice at: 6,5
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
Child placed peice at: 3,1
 R  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
Child placed peice at: 5,4
 R  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
Child placed peice at: 5,7
 B  B  B  B  -  R  B  R 
 R  R  B  B  R  R  B  B 
Child placed peice at: 2,2
```

This should print like this:

```
Winner Parent
Winning Parent (20): 26181
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -  - 
 B  -  -  R  -  -  -  - 
 B  -  -  R  B  -  -  - 
 B  -  -  R  B  B  R  R 
 R  R  -  R  R  B  B  B
```

Is there a way to stop the other processes stop their printing when I print the winning board?

Comment: You need to set up some communication between the processes so that one process can tell the other to stop printing.

Comment: I have pipes to communicate, but for some reason it still prints when I tell it not to.

Comment: post your code. Maybe you do not check in which process you are when doing the specific operations. Take into account that `fork()` returns the pid of the child in the parent process and 0 in the child process.

Comment: direct "diagnostic" output (the children's intermediate results) to stderr, and send the "real" result (the parent) to stdout. After building, you can choose to redirect stderr (eg to a log file, or /dev/null), or omit it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sprintf` to print to a string, then use `printf` on that string with a `fflush(stdout)` to flush to the io stream.  This will keep the processes from interleaving output.

I believe this issue is a bigger issue though, what are you trying to do?  Can you write the child processes to another file?

Comment: I am having my child and parent play connect four, when a winner is found I print the board, which is a 2D int array.

Comment: What I described will work then, just have each process flush the stream after each `printf` have the parent build the final result in memory using a string and then print at the end.  You may still want to look at named pipes or sockets to take the parent child communication off stdout and stdin.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely normal to overlap the print statements in different processes because the run at the same time. You can `wait()` for the process you want to not overlap the prints with the other processes, but in the case you will lose concurrency.

Another solution would be to use some synchronization mechanisms such as a semaphore or mutex.